# How to run a task after gulp.watch complete and still continue watching?

Tags: laravel, sass, gulp, laravel-elixir

So I'm struggling to have both `watch` and `mix` working together.

I have my gulpfile which do something like that for watching sass :

```
gulp.task('default',function(){
    gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/css/'));

    gulp.watch('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
})
```

I have too my mixing script which use the output of the task before to do my css file :

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles(
        [
            "../metronic/global/css/components-rounded.css",
            "../metronic/global/css/plugins.css",
            "../metronic/admin/layout3/css/layout.css",
            "../metronic/admin/layout3/css/custom.css",
            "../metronic/admin/pages/css/timeline.css",
            "../dist/sweetalert.css",
            "../dist/toastr.min.css",
            "../css/global.css",
        ],
        'public/css/layout.css'
    );
}
```

The thing is I don't get how to combine both since If I put my `watch` into the `elixir(function)` it stop the process and if I put it after ward it will work only on `gulp` once.

My question could then be : **How to run a task after gulp.watch complete and still continue watching?**

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your all `.scss` files are not prefixed with `_`. If you prefix the `.scss` files with `_`, then the scss parser will not compile the `.scss` file as a independent file. So, technically you don't need `elixir` (*Again, assuming elixir is used to combine all css files*) here. You gulp code will be just:

```
gulp.task('default',function(){
    gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/css/'));

    gulp.watch('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
})
```

Now, do the following:

- Prefix all the `.scss` files with `_`. Example: `_components-rounder.scss`, `_plugins.scss` etc.
- Create a `layout.scss` (without `_` prefix) and insert the following code in it:

---

```
@import "relative/path/to/components-rounder";
@import "relative/path/to/plugins";
// Include all other scss files below without underscore prefix and extension as I shown above
```

Comment: Nice idea but I needed to use elixir :/ I've finally manage to do it and posted an answer below :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [gulp-batch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-batch)

```
npm install gulp-batch --save-dev
```

Run your sass stuff somewhere else and let watch do what it does while running your sass on changes

```
var batch = require('gulp-batch');

gulp.task('default',function(){
    gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error',sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/css/'));
})

gulp.task('watch',function(){
    // Run watch
    gulp.watch('resources/assets/sass/**/*.scss',['styles'], batch(function(events, cb) {
      // run every time on changes
      gulp.start('default', cb);
    }));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok After hour of loosing my hair here is the solution :

First of all you **must** use `elixir` however I haven't found proper solution working an other way.

Fairly easy when you see it : `mix.sass("*.scss","resources/assets/css/global.css");`

Once you've done that **instead of using just `gulp` use `gulp watch`** which will look for any changement in the files of your elixir function.

Since it contain the files modified by `mix.sass(...)` it will automatically relaunch the mixing of your style.

### Finally it look like this :

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass("*.scss","resources/assets/css/global.css");

    mix.styles(
        [
            "../metronic/global/css/components-rounded.css",
            "../metronic/global/css/plugins.css",
            "../metronic/admin/layout3/css/layout.css",
            "../metronic/admin/layout3/css/custom.css",
            "../metronic/admin/pages/css/timeline.css",
            "../dist/sweetalert.css",
            "../dist/toastr.min.css",
            "../css/global.css",
        ],
        'public/css/layout.css'
    );

}
```